# Is there a way to obtain the most recently uploaded homebrew packages (formulae)?

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I have discovered some absolute command-line gems by looking at the commit history of homebrew formula. i.e. this URL: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commits/master/Formula.

However, this manual method is quite tedious. I need to load the commit history on the browser, click on each individual commit to see the name of the package, and then do a `brew info recently_discovered_formula` to understand what it does.

Is there a way (e.g. a shell script/function/ etc) that can be used to obtain the name of the most recent *x* number of new packages, right from the command line?

Comment: A very interesting problem/idea, but requests for tools (or work) are off topic here. AND I'm not a git master, but wouldn't `git clone <site>` at least get all to code/etc to your local machine, where it should be easier to parse? Edit your question with some reasonable attempt to solve the problem, include the exact error messages and readers may be able to help. Good luck.

Comment: Have you check out the brew api, https://formulae.brew.sh/docs/api/?